# I want to split a table in to two rows using media query

Tags: html

i want to split this table into 2 rows because its overflowing i want to split it from skill certification deployment matrix with table head and put it below respective employee  name,id row one by one

[enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpob.jpg[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBpob.jpg%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLq1y.jpg))

front-end code

```
<div class="col-md-12 mg-b-15">
        <div class="annual-training-plan sdm-box skill-certification">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sdm-title col-md-6">
                    <h3>Skill Certification & Deployment Matrix</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="demo-table col-md-6">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="foo blue"> </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>  Plan</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="foo yellow"> </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>  Recertification</span>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <span class="foo green"> </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>  Certified</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="foo gray"> </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>  No Plan</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="matrix-graph">
                <table id="deploymentMatrixTbl" class="table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="wd-20p emp-detail">Employee Name</th>


                            <th scope="col" class="wd-15p emp-detail">Employee Id</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="wd-15p emp-detail">Department</th>

                            <th scope="col" class="wd-7p emp-detail"> Role</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="wd-90p emp-detail"><span>Skill Certification & Deployment Matrix</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td colspan="4">No data available.</td></tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux5Ff.jpg
```

Comment: Some code(snipped) whitout screenshot would be good..

Comment: Just added code can you have a look?

Comment: what bootstrap do you use?